# Json Object to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jscript, github-api

I have a simple page with a "button/link" when i press the button i need to call the github api to return all issues logged in my repository and show in table format.

But when i hit the link nothing happends..

```
   <html>
<head>

    <script src="json-to-table.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script.responsive.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>All Issues</h2>
    <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="art-button">VIEW</a>

    <div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#ghapidata').html('<div id="loader"><img src="css/loader.gif" alt="loader..."></div>');

            var ghissues = 'https://api.github.com/repos/stroes/stroestest/issues';

            requestJson(ghissues, function(json) {
                if(json.message == "Not Found") {
                    $('#ghapidata').html("<h2>No Issues found in this repository</h2>");
                }

                else {
                    var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(ghissues, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');

                }

            }
        }
    });





</script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone point me to where i have gone wrong with my code

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with all fo the code attached?

Answer (score 0):

your script is inside your div tag. When you change the html inside it, whole script will be removed. Try to place the script outside the div tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="json-to-table.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="script.responsive.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>All Issues</h2>
<a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="art-button">VIEW</a>

<div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {
    $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#ghapidata').html('<div id="loader"><img src="css/loader.gif" alt="loader..."></div>');

        var ghissues = 'https://api.github.com/repos/stroes/stroestest/issues';

        requestJson(ghissues, function(json) {
            if(json.message == "Not Found") {
                $('#ghapidata').html("<h2>No Issues found in this repository</h2>");
            }

            else {
                var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(ghissues, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');

            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see errors in your console. You didn't close the functions right

```
$(function () {
    $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#ghapidata').html('<div id="loader"><img src="css/loader.gif" alt="loader..."></div>');

        var ghissues = 'https://api.github.com/repos/stroes/stroestest/issues';

        requestJson(ghissues, function (json) {
            if (json.message == "Not Found") {
                $('#ghapidata').html("<h2>No Issues found in this repository</h2>");
            } else {
                var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(ghissues, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');

            }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please look here again

```
    var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(ghissues, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');
```

The second parameter requires id of your table you have no table with id jsonTable i think that is the problem